The SysOut isn't working properly. How do I fix this?
So...
I'm having problems with sysout and it's not printing the last part of my code. Here are the two files and my results:


public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flower tulip1 = new Flower(1, "tulip");
        Flower rose1 = new Flower(3, 45.21, "rose");
        Flower tulip2 = new Flower(2, 39.881, "tulip");
        Flower dandelion1 = new Flower(0, 0, "dandelion");

        if (tulip1.Compare(tulip2) == true) {
          System.out.println("These two flowers are the same type.");
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("These two flowers are not the same type.");
        }

        if (rose1.Compare(dandelion1)) {
          System.out.println("These two flowers are the same type.");
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("These two flowers are not the same type.");
        }

        System.out.println(rose1.ReturnHeightAndStage());

      
        tulip1.Age();
        
        tulip1.randomPollenPercentage();
        tulip1.pollenCheck();

        dandelion1.Grow(5.86);
        rose1.setPollenPercentage(78.9971);

     }
}

public class Flower {
    private int stage;
    private double heightInCM;
    private String flowerType;
    private double pollenPercentage;

    public Flower(int s, double h, String ft) {
        stage = s;
        flowerType = ft;
        heightInCM = h;
    }
    public Flower(int s, String ft) {
        stage = s;
        flowerType = ft;
        heightInCM = 0;
    }
    public void Age() {
        if (stage < 3){
            stage += 1;
        }
    }
    public void Grow(double growth) {
        heightInCM += growth;
    }
    public boolean Compare(Flower anyFlower) {
        if (this.flowerType.equals(anyFlower.flowerType)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void setPollenPercentage(double newValue) {
        if (newValue > 100.00) {
            newValue = 100.00;
        }
        if (newValue < 0.00) {
            newValue = 0.00;
        }
        pollenPercentage = newValue;
    }
    public void randomPollenPercentage() {
        pollenPercentage = Math.random() * 100.00;
    }

    public String ReturnHeightAndStage() {
        double height = this.heightInCM;
        int growthStage = this.stage;

        if (growthStage == 1) {
            return "Your flower is " + height + " centimeters tall, and it is a BUD.";
        }
        else if (growthStage == 2) {
            return "Your flower is " + height + " centimeters tall, and it is a SPROUT.";
        }
        else if (growthStage == 3) {
            return "Your flower is " + height + " centimeters tall, and it is a FULL-GROWN FLOWER.";
        }
        else {
            this.heightInCM = 0;
            return "Your flower has died mysteriously.";
        }
    }
    public void pollenCheck() {
        if (pollenPercentage > 100.00) {
            pollenPercentage = 100.00;
        }
        if (pollenPercentage == 100.00) {
            System.out.println("Your flower is in perfect health! Good job!");
        }
        else if (pollenPercentage >= 90.00) {
            System.out.println("Your flower is in great health.");
        }
        else if (pollenPercentage >= 75.00) {
            System.out.println("Your flower is in good health. It could be better.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Your flower is dead due to unhealthy conditions.");
        }
    }
}

Tried everything. Tried changing the code segment, altering the Flower class, etc. Nothing worked. I need help to make the second Compare() method call work (unless the problem is with the SysOut, in which case I need help fixing that).

Please add the code in form of formatted text. Do not add pictures as we cannot properly see the code, edit, or copy it. You cannot, either.

Are you also compiling the new code before running? I only see you run java, and not javac.

The problem I'm having is the second time I use the Compare() method as a parameter in an if-else condition, it isn't running the TRUE or the FALSE segments

Yeah, got it now. But still, the images show that you are only running the program, but not compiling it

WTF is SysOut from title? How is it related to "The problem I'm having is the second time I use the Compare() method", from text and comment?
